# Who acts as load balancer if I have several dispathers in cq5 web application?

Tags: java, load-balancing, aem, dispatcher, publisher

As I understand, usually in CQ5 dispatcher acts as load balancer.

But I know that our instance has several dispatchers.

I imagine this like so:

[image]

What do you think about this picture? Is it possible variant?

Which variants are possible else?

What does act as load balancer at this case?

Comment: We usually just have one disptacher per publish instance and never used it as a load balancer. Check the documentation at http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html

Comment: But I know that we have several dispatcher per environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sector of devices called Hardware Load Balancers that are a part of network layer that can act as top level load balancers. This item looks similar to hub/router but is able to balance the traffic.

Quite often, load balancing is solved on the cloud e.g. Amazon provides such functionality through [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). This way it's a provider responsibility to divide the traffic equally and care about system durability via healthchecks.